# TinyMCE file_picker_callback select image from default browser file selection

Tags: file-upload, tinymce, tinymce-4, filechooser

Im using TinyMCE in a project and want the user to select and upload images to the server using its default insert image window.

I want to click the following button:

[image]

Open the browsers default file select window and add the selected image to the editor:

[image]

My code so far is as follows..

JS:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '#html-editor',
        language: 'pt_PT',
        plugins: [
            "bdesk_photo advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code media nonbreaking",
            "table contextmenu directionality paste textcolor colorpicker imagetools"
        ],
        add_unload_trigger: false,
        toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media preview | forecolor backcolor table",
        image_advtab: true,

        file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta)
        {
            $('#html-editor input').click();

            //how to get selected image data and add to editor?
        },

        paste_data_images: true,
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure)
        {
            // no upload, just return the blobInfo.blob() as base64 data
            success("data:" + blobInfo.blob().type + ";base64," + blobInfo.base64());
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="html-editor">
    <input name="image" type="file" style="width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;">
</div>
```

What kind of changes must i make to the *file_picker_callback* event in order to get the selected file and add it to the editor?

Comment: You should really mark @Karl Morrisons answer as correct one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same problem. Using the following fixed it for me, remember that the browser must support FileReader (otherwise just insert your own script).

html (put this anywhere on the html page):

```
<input id="my-file" type="file" name="my-file" style="display: none;" onchange="" />
```

js (in the tinymce init config):

```
file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
    if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
        var input = document.getElementById('my-file');
        input.click();
        input.onchange = function () {
            var file = input.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                callback(e.target.result, {
                    alt: file.name
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also create that input field on the fly inside file_picker_callback and remove once you have read the picked file into memory.

Comment: There's a demo on TinyMCE site, that makes use of blob URIs instead: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/file-picker/

Comment: thanks but after uploading image screen just got froze and after some time asking me to kill the page. please help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var imageFilePicker = function (callback, value, meta) {               
    tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Image Picker',
        url: '/images/getimages',
        width: 650,
        height: 550,
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Insert',
            onclick: function () {
                //.. do some work
                tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Close',
            onclick: 'close'
        }],
    }, {
        oninsert: function (url) {
            callback(url);
            console.log("derp");
        },
    });
};


tinymce.init({
  selector: 'div#html-editor',
  height: 200,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
  image_advtab: true,
  paste_data_images: true,
  automatic_uploads: true,
  file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
    imageFilePicker(callback, value, meta);
  }
 });
```

Comment: your solution is for a custom file manager, what i would like to do is use the browsers default file chooser to select a local image:  [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DVYxF.png)